# Regular expressions string splits

Tags: regex, vb.net

I'm trying to create a pattern that enables me split a string on comas but ignoring expressions within curly brackets.

my existing code works great if only one group of curly bracket expressions exist in the string.

```
Dim expression As New Regex(",(?=(?:[^\{]*\{[^\{]*\})*(?![^\}]*\}))")

        Try
            parts = expression.Split(sortString)
            For Each Item In parts
                If Not Item Is Nothing Then
                    result.Add(Item)
                End If
            Next

            Return result
```

If I pass the string

```
{IIF(Hemo.Site = "LV",1,IIF(Hemo.Site = "SVC",2,IIF(Hemo_Pressures.Site = "AO",3,4)))},Site DESC,Pressure1 ASC
```

It works, the curly bracket grouping is ignored and each string after is broken out with the coma split.

Problem is.  If I need to accommodate multiple groupings of curly bracket expressions in my string and it begins to fail.

This fails:

```
{IIF(Hemo.Site = "LV",1,IIF(Hemo.Site = "SVC",2,IIF(Hemo_Pressures.Site = "AO",3,4)))},Site DESC,{IIF(Hemo.Site = "LV",1,IIF(Hemo.Site = "SVC",2,IIF(Hemo.Site = "AO",3,4)))}, Pressure1 ASC
```

one of the grouping is ignored as it should be, but the other grouping of curly brackets is not.  Resulting in a dirty collection.

I would appreciate a second pair of eyes on this.

Comment: Try this `,(?![^{]*\})`.  I haven't done exhaustive testing, but it seems to be working for me.

Comment: Works perfect... much more elegant than my pattern thanks.

Comment: I found some issues if there is text containing '}' between commas it should be splitting, for example `1,2,{1,2,3},4,5,}6` doesn't split correctly.  Hopefully that won't be a problem for you.

Comment: I think that should not be a problem.  Each open should have a closing and there should not be any nested curlies in my use.  --Trying to figure out how to mark that as answer.

Comment: I'll type it up as a proper answer that you can mark, give me a minute or 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pattern `,(?![^{]*\})` seems to be working for me, as long as there are no lose `{` or `}` floating around in the text.

Broken down, it evaluates as

> ```
> ,
> zero-width negative lookahead
>   Any character not in "{"
>   * (zero or more times)
>   }
> End Capture
> ```

You can use `*,(?![^{]*\}) *` to trim the spaces immediately before and after commas if required.

---

On your test string, it produces the follow splits:

- {IIF(Hemo.Site = "LV",1,IIF(Hemo.Site =
  "SVC",2,IIF(Hemo_Pressures.Site = "AO",3,4)))}
- Site DESC
- {IIF(Hemo.Site = "LV",1,IIF(Hemo.Site = "SVC",2,IIF(Hemo.Site =
  "AO",3,4)))}
- Pressure1 ASC

However, it will fail to properly split strings like

> Apple, Ban}ana, Carrot {1,2,3}, Frog, Cat, 1,2,3

due to the lose `}` in "banana"

Comment: Thanks I was beating my head against a wall!